# Is there a way to display valid json in a collapsable format in Angular 2?

Tags: json, angular

Is there a way to display valid json in a collapsable format in Angular 2?

`<pre> {{data | json}} </pre>`

will display the json nicely but I need the ability to collapse/expand the  individual objects within.

Comment: you should try this: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-tree

Comment: @Fals looked into that but that requires a 'tree' structure so I'd have to convert the json.

Comment: You will need to iterate through your JSON using keys and build the tree, there's no way to avoid It, you need a component to show It.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try ngx-json-viewer. It's perfect for displaying json objects with expandable/collapsible nodes and arrays

https://github.com/hivivo/ngx-json-viewer

Comment: I would like to add that this library is no longer working on Angular 8+. Unfortunately, the repo is also dead.

Comment: @Kazu its back with Angular 11 support