# Angular tree from JSON response

Tags: angular

I have a response like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "ab",
        "description": "gazeta",
        "published": true,
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "content": null
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "content": null
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "content": null
            }
        ]
    }            
]
```

How can I make tree in Angular? Any examples of impelementation, or documentation, or working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an interface:

```
export interface yourInterface{
    id: number;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    published: boolean;
    comments: {id: number; content: string;}[]
```

}

and declare your http request like this:

```
this.httpService.get<yourInterface[]>('url...')
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/hivivo/ngx-json-viewer

There is a json viewer.

Please ask your questions a bit more specific.
A google search took me 1 second `angular folding json`

[Is there a way to display valid json in a collapsable format in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41771536/is-there-a-way-to-display-valid-json-in-a-collapsable-format-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

I hade same problem and i used Angular Material-Tree

https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples

Hope this helps!